# Check if string has some special characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to do a check for multiple special characters and replace them later with regular letters. I've tried to use Regex and regular expressions like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(toCheck, @"[^&\,\ß]"))
{
    toCheck = toCheck.Replace("&", "and");
    toCheck = toCheck.Replace(",", "");
    toCheck = toCheck.Replace("ß", "ss");

    return toCheck;
}
```

And the problem is that Regex apparently does not work with ASCII codes, like ß or Ö, Æ, Å, Ä are, since I am getting an exception about not knowing what 
\ß is. Is there any other way to check multiple characters in string that is easier than to write big if loop like:

```
if(toCheck.Contains("Ö") || toCheck.Contains("Æ") || ... )
```

Because I have to do that for 15 special symbols and it will be kind of messy.

Comment: there is not need for \ when writing `ß` or `,`

Comment: Why don't you just replace? If they are not there, nothing bad happens.

Comment: For `,` it is @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: Why do the regex check at all? Why not just apply all of the `Replace`s anyway?